# What would be a better method for numerical diagonalization of a certain Vandermonde-like matrix?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvalues

For the fractional iteration of the $\exp()$-function Hellmuth Kneser had 1942 proposed an analytic solution valid on the real numbers; there is a technical implementation for Pari/GP of this method available (online in the "Tetration-Forum"), so actual values can be computed.
In a current discussion it occured that possibly the Kneser-method is asymptotic to a very simple method which diagonalizes a certain (Carleman)-matrix, say $B$.
To get more heuristics for the approximation (which seems depend on the size of the matrix $B$ ) I need a very efficient method for the determination of the eigenvalues of that matrix.
However, the builtin diagonalization-routine in Pari/GP , though surely optimized, needs some minutes for B of size 32x32 with at least 600 digits precision and for *B* of size 64x64 it needs 4000 digits precision and works 2 hours on my computer. From this it seems impossible to think of 128x128 or 256x256 matrices.

Also, it may be, that the specific form of the matrix has some analytic description of its eigenvalues - as for instance for the determinant of a Vandermonde-matrix.   Here $B$ is a factorially row-scaled Vandermonde matrix of the form
$$ B = \small {\operatorname{diag}[1,w,w^2/2!,w^3/3!,...w^4/n!] \cdot \begin{bmatrix} {} 1&1&1&1&1&...&1 \\ 0&1&2&3&4&...&n\\
0&1&2^2&3^2&4^2&...&n^2 \\
0&1&2^3&3^3&4^3&...&n^3 \\ ...     \\ 
0&1&2^n&3^n&4^n&...&n^n \\ ...     \\ 
\end{bmatrix} }$$    or 
$$B := \left\{   {(wc)^r \over r!}   \right\} _{r=0..n,c=0..n}  $$

From my heuristics I've got the very vague impression, that the eigenvalues go somehow roughly $a^{k^2}$ with k the index and $a$ some constant and with bigger size $B_{nxn}$ this approximates better.

***Q:*** is there a more efficient eigenvalue-solver available
or - is there even an analytic estimate for the eigenvalues depending on the size-parameter *n* available?

---

***[updat:e]***
Trying to find an analytical expression for the eigenvalues, I list the characteristic polynomials of the first few matrices with sizes *2x2,3x3,4x4,5x5* as coefficients-matrices:
$$ \small { \begin{array}{r|rrrr} 
 C_2:&. & 1 \\ 
 & -1 & . \\  
 \hline\\ 
 C_3:& . & . & 1 \\ 
& . & -1 & . \\  
& . & -2 & .\\  
& 1 & . & . \\ 
\hline \\
 C_4:&  . & . & . & 2 \\  
&  . & . & -2 & . \\  
&  . & . & -4 & . \\  
&  . & 2 & -9 & . \\  
&  . & 8 & . & . \\  
&  . & 6 & . & . \\  
&  -2 & . & . & . \\  
\hline \\
 C_5:&  . & . & . & . & 6 \\  
&  . & . & . & -6 & . \\  
&  . & . & . & -12 & . \\  
&  . & . & 6 & -27 & . \\  
&  . & . & 24 & -64 & . \\  
&  . & . & 81 & . & . \\  
&  . & -6 & 96 & . & . \\  
&  . & -42 & 72 & . & . \\  
&  . & -57 & . & . & . \\  
&  . & -24 & . & . & . \\  
&  6 & . & . & . & . & \\  
\hline \\
 \end{array}}
$$
They must be constructed by dotproducts of vectors $W=[1,w,w^2,w^3,...]$ and $X=[1,x,x^2,x^3,...]$ such that for instance the characteristic polynomial $\text{cp}_2$ for size *2x2* is constructed by
$\text{cp}_2 = W \cdot C_2 \cdot X^T $ and the eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial given some parameter *w*. (The matrices $C$ are scaled by some factor such that they are expressible in integer coefficients only. Also the matrices are reduced such that the general root *x=1* is already removed).

It would now be helpful if the matrices $C$ could be constructed by some recursive rule to avoid the need to compute the actual characteristic polynomial of a *nxn* -matrix.